# Getting Unique Values in XML Data

Tags: python, xml

Sort of a two part question.

First here is the code I'm currently trying to work with. I'd like to stick with lxml over BS.

```
import requests
import lxml.etree
from requests.auth import HTTPBasicAuth

r= requests.get("https://somelinkhere/folder/?parameter=abc", auth=HTTPBasicAuth('username', 'password'))

root = lxml.etree.fromstring(r.content)
results = root.findall('entry')
textnumbers = [r.find('updated').text for r in results]
print (textnumbers)
```

Output just gives me `[]`

and the XML data I'm working with:

```
<feed xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom" xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#" xmlns:geo="http://www.w3.org/2003/01/geo/wgs84_pos#" xmlns:apple-wallpapers="http://www.apple.com/ilife/wallpapers" xmlns:g-custom="http://base.google.com/cns/1.0" xmlns:taxo="http://purl.org/rss/1.0/modules/taxonomy/" xmlns:opensearch="http://a9.com/-/spec/opensearch/1.1/" xmlns:media="http://search.yahoo.com/mrss/" xmlns:sy="http://purl.org/rss/1.0/modules/syndication/" xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/" xmlns:georss="http://www.georss.org/georss/" xmlns:creativeCommons="http://backend.userland.com/creativeCommonsRssModule" xmlns:cc="http://web.resource.org/cc/" xmlns:slash="http://purl.org/rss/1.0/modules/slash/" xmlns:g-core="http://base.google.com/ns/1.0">
  <title>Feed from some link here</title>
  <link rel="self" href="https://somelinkhere/folder/?parameter=abc" />
  <link rel="first" href="https://somelinkhere/folder/?parameter=abc" />
  <id>https://somelinkhere/folder/?parameter=abc</id>
  <updated>2018-03-06T17:48:09Z</updated>
  <dc:creator>company.com</dc:creator>
  <dc:date>2018-03-06T17:48:09Z</dc:date>
  <opensearch:totalResults>4</opensearch:totalResults>
  <opensearch:startIndex>1</opensearch:startIndex>
  <entry>
    <title>123456789</title>
    <link rel="alternate" href="https://somelink/ticket/123456789" />
    <author>
      <name>usernameHere</name>
    </author>
    <id>https://somelink/ticket/123456789</id>
    <updated>2018-02-28T13:27:33Z</updated>
    <content>short_description$$$someTextHere</content>
    <summary>some summary here</summary>
    <dc:creator>usernameHere</dc:creator>
  </entry>
  <entry>
    <title>123456799</title>
    <link rel="alternate" href="https://somelink/ticket/123456799" />
    <author>
      <name>usernameHere</name>
    </author>
    <id>https://somelink/ticket/123456799</id>
    <updated>2018-03-20113:27:33Z</updated>
    <content>short_description$$$someTextHere</content>
    <summary>some summary here</summary>
    <dc:creator>usernameHere</dc:creator>
  </entry>
```

First thing I'm trying to do is just get the dates from the `<entry>` -> `<updated>` field.

Second part is to count the unique dates. So if I get the following dates.
2018-02-27
2018-02-27
2018-02-28
2018-03-01

I'd have a count of 3.

However, second part is just a bonus. I'm more concerned on how to get those values out of the XML to work with and I'm not sure how to do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to incorporate an existing namespace when parsing XML structure:

```
root = lxml.etree.fromstring(r.content)
ns = {'ns': 'http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom'}
dates = [d.text for d in root.findall('ns:entry/ns:updated', ns)]

print(dates)
```

The output:

```
['2018-02-28T13:27:33Z', '2018-03-20113:27:33Z']
```

Answer (score 0):

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

soup = BeautifulSoup(r,'xml')
updates = soup.findAll('updated')
for update in updates:
    print(update.contents)
```

That should work. Try it out. it should take very little tinkering if that doesn't work as is.

edit: `find()` will only find the first occurrence `findAll()` or `find_all()`  will find them all